# How to capture delimiters also as tokens in result

Tags: java

Below is the code for creating tokens based on delimiters. This will give the tokens but will not consider delimiters in token result. If we want to include the delimiters also in result, what should be the approach.

```
StringTokenizer tr=
new StringTokenizer("Will you come, yes/no",",/");
while (tr.hasMoreElements( ))
System.out.println(tr.nextElement( )+",");
```

So output should be tokens as:

Will, ,you, ,come, ,yes,/,no,

(Instead of just will,you,come,yes,no,)

Comment: I'm not sure if I understood your requirements clearly but it will give what you expect if your string is like `"Will you come, yes, /, no"`

Comment: Instead of just "will,you,come,yes,no" i want results as "Will, ,you, ,come, ,yes,/,no'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`/` is not coming as one of the tokens because it is not surrounded by the delimiter. If you want it to be parsed as one of the tokens then you can surround it with delimiters.

Here is the code snippet:

```
public static void main (String[] args)
{
    String sample = "Will you come,yes/no";
    StringTokenizer tr = new StringTokenizer(sample.replace(" ",",").replace("/",",/,"),",");
    while (tr.hasMoreElements())
        System.out.println(tr.nextElement() + ",");
}
```

Output:

```
Will,
you,
come,
yes,
/,
no,
```

Comment: I need it as Will, ,you, ,come, ,yes,/,no.Space sould be treated as token and will,you,come should be 3 different tokens.

Comment: In that case, you need to replace the spaces with delims too. Please check the updated solution.

Comment: Thanks. I got one more solution to use a " true " indicator like in eg: StringTokenizer st = 
 new StringTokenizer("Hello, World|of|Java", ", |", true);
while (st.hasMoreElements( ))
 System.out.println("Token: " + st.nextElement( ));